# 2D PointCloud to Occupancy grid

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm having trouble finding a package that does what I want. I'm using the Intel's Euclid to scan the room and I extract every possible plane with help of the PointCloud Library. I can store those planes for later inspection. What I need to do now is creating an occupancy grid, i.e. a matrix with cells that represent 1cm^2 with the probability of occupancy (0-100)
I researched and found the octomap_server and the ethz-asl/grid_map package but I'm not sure they serve my purpose.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288003/2d-pointcloud-to-occupancy-grid/) by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [Gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping), It performs SLAM with odometry and 2D laser scanner. It gives the  2D map and entropy as well. You can change the parameters inside the programs or in `.yml` file.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on 2018-04-09**:
Inputs for Gmapping are tf (tf/tfMessage) and scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan), and I would like to use my 2D PointCloud plane. Any alternatives?

Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
Not pushing you to use `gmapping`, but there is something called [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan).

**Comment by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on 2018-04-10**:
Thanks for your answer @gvdhoorn , but it doesn't seem to match what I'm looking for. What I have is a dataset of points that represent a plane (for indoor purposes, to be more precise, e.g a table or a wall) and I need to know how probable it is for the robot to wander through that plane.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
My comment was in response to your "I have a pointcloud, not a laser scanner" comment earlier.